# Enter a Carriage Return in a Crystal Reports Parameter Field

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I'm trying to use a parameter field as a notes box for a report, where when you run it, you can freely enter notes into the parameter and it will display as a text box on the form.
However, I've found you cannot enter a Carriage Return(new line).

Anyone know a way to enter a new line in a parameter for crystal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Created a parameter field called notes, then a formula field to alter the notes.

```
Replace ({?Notes},"." ,"."&ChrW (10) )
```

That replaces any periods with a .period and a new line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Crystal can handle multi-line parameters. You could use multiple parameters, one for each line, or use a printable character like `#` as a placeholder in the text, and substitute it with newlines in a formula.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to create a Formula Field which Can Grow and use text & carriage return & text

e.g.

```
"This is how to do a" & CHR(13) & "Line Break"
```

Will appear as:-

```
This is how to do a
Line Break
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, with SAP Crystal reports, you can use a JavaScript line break ("br" surrounded by "<>") to split the parameter prompt into two or more lines, just plop it into the prompt text wherever you want a new line.  A little off topic, but I came here to find this and figured I'd leave it here for anyone else.

And for added fun, you can use the "img src" tag to directly embed images into a parameter, dunno why you would but you can.