# Line Feed Does Not Work For Crystal Report Text Field

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, textfield

I have a working Application, There is an update to append text with a text field and I need to add Line Break as well to see Line break effects in Crystal Report Text Object, I am doing with various ways but no change is reflecting in Report Viewer.

```
 DECLARE @NewLineChar AS VARCHAR(2)   
 SET @NewLineChar = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
 SELECT @NewLineChar + 'New Text Appending Here' + @NewLineChar
    + dbo.employees.first_name
 FROM   dbo.employees
```

I can't see any change any line break in crystal report filed area.

Comment: Play with text interpretation in field format options - maybe helps.

Comment: I just noticed that this field in Boxed in TextObject in Crystal Report with another field, I guess by this all formatting get ignore.

Comment: And I have to change only in Script side, because the application can't be updated with .exe replacement at the moment.

Comment: Embedding field into text field should not affect formatting. I tried with formula field (not database one) inside text field - line break is accepted by default. Are you sure your report itself doesn't remove line breaks (using some formula)? Or some other part of SQL overwriting your newlines?

Comment: Maybe this can help [Enter a Carriage Return in Crystal Reports parameter field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201262/enter-a-carriage-return-in-a-crystal-reports-parameter-field/50383652#50383652)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching with code and playing with report designer and got to know that, embedded field's Text interpretation was in HTML so I added `<br>` tags and `<p>` tags for the required.

```
 DECLARE @NewLineChar AS VARCHAR(2)   
 SET @NewLineChar = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
 SELECT + 'New Texte Appending Here' + '<br><p>     </p>'
    + dbo.employees.first_name
 FROM   dbo.employees
```